# file is not downloaded as a fileName instead file_key in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, file, download

When i click on the fileName, It will download the file successfully(d7f1eb91-6a65-4fde-8151-d9fb6afb7cfb_Desert.jpg). but I expect to download as Desert.jpg. Can you help to find out the Issue?

Html:

```
    <p *ngIf="removebtn" (click)="showPdf(employeeDetails.certificateurl)" class="wordBreak"><a style="cursor: pointer;" target="_blank">{{(employeeDetails.showcertificateurl)}}</a> 
       <i class="fa fa-times" style="color:red; cursor: pointer;font-size: 20px; margin-left: 10px;" aria-hidden="true" (click)="removeImage()">
       </i>
    </p>
```

component:

```
showPdf(file) {
    console.log(file)
      //https://testkimage.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/upload/image/d7f1eb91-6a65-4fde-8151-d9fb6afb7cfb_Desert.jpg
      const linkSource = file;
      const downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
      let fileName = "";
      downloadLink.href = linkSource;
      console.log(downloadLink)
      //<a href="https://testkimagek.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/upload/image/d7f1eb91-6a65-4fde-8151-d9fb6afb7cfb_Desert.jpg" download="Desert.jpg"></a>
      fileName = this.splitunderscore(linkSource)
      console.log(fileName)
      //Desert.jpg
      if (fileName)
           downloadLink.setAttribute('download', fileName);
      document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
      downloadLink.click();
      document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
    }

splitunderscore(data){
  return data.split('_')[1];
}
 removeImage(){
    this.removebtn = false;
    // console.log(this.removebtn);
    this.employeeDetails.certificateurl = "";
    this.employeeDetails.showcertificateurl = "";
  }
```

Comment: Can you add a comment lines after each `console.log`, to see the result output ?

Comment: @Random, I have added console.log lines, You can check now.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is a browser security feature.  [Chrome](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/4969697975992320), [Mozilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=676619) and (I'm assuming) Edge ignore the download attribute if the target is cross-origin.

The only solutions I can come up with are:

1. Rename the source object to the desired filename.
2. Add an intermediary server to proxy the file with the desired filename.
3. Use Ajax to download the image and then serve it up inline like this:

```
fetch('https://<ImageURL>').then((blob) => {
  const ele = document.createElement('a');
  ele.href = 'data:image/jpeg,' + encodeURI(blob);
  ele.target = '_new';
  ele.download = 'desert.jpg';
  ele.click();
});
```

Make sure your S3 bucket's CORS policy has your domain listed.